# Issue with nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue with a nested ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="IS in ISList">

            ...

            <div ng-repeat="area in areaList">
                <h5 ng-if="hasAreaResult(IS, area)">{{area}}</h5>
                <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-lg="3" md-cols-gt-lg="4"
                              md-row-height-gt-md="1.25:1" md-row-height="1:1"
                              md-gutter="10px" md-gutter-gt-sm="10px" class="grid">

                    <md-grid-tile class="gray" ng-repeat="carto in filterCartoList()" class="slide" ng-if="carto.informationSystem == IS && carto.type != 'AM' && carto.type != 'IF' && carto.area == area && !carto.block  && carto.level != 'theme'">
                        <md-button ng-click="changeSVG(carto.fileName)" aria-label="carto.displayName">
                            <img src="style/images/thumbnails/{{carto.fileName}}.png" width="100%" height="100%" title="{{carto.fullDisplayName}}" style="max-height: 220px;"></img>
                        </md-button>
                        <md-grid-tile-footer><h3 align="center">{{carto.displayName}}</h3> </md-grid-tile-footer>
                    </md-grid-tile>

                </md-grid-list>

                <div ng-repeat="block in blockList">
                    <h6 ng-if="hasBlockResult(IS, area, block)">{{block}}</h6>
                    <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-lg="3" md-cols-gt-lg="4"
                                  md-row-height-gt-md="1.25:1" md-row-height="1:1"
                                  md-gutter="10px" md-gutter-gt-sm="10px" class="grid">

                        <md-grid-tile class="gray" ng-repeat="carto in filterCartoList()" class="slide" ng-if="carto.informationSystem == IS && carto.type != 'AM' && carto.type != 'IF' && carto.area == area && carto.block == block && carto.level != 'theme'"> 
                            <md-button ng-click="changeSVG(carto.fileName)" aria-label="carto.displayName">
                                <img src="style/images/thumbnails/{{carto.fileName}}.png" width="100%" height="100%" title="{{carto.fullDisplayName}}" style="max-height: 220px;"></img>
                            </md-button>
                            <md-grid-tile-footer><h3 align="center">{{carto.displayName}}</h3> </md-grid-tile-footer>
                        </md-grid-tile>

                    </md-grid-list>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Since I added the `<div ng-repeat="block in blockList">` block, my browser looks stucked in loading and crashes.
The loops are not that long, so I don't know why this is having this behavior

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the IDE. It thinks that these are HTML attributes and since there is no attribute with that name, it says it is not allowed.

To solve this problem prefix with `data-`. This will make the attribute valid, and the error will not be show.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="block in blockList">
    <h6 data-ng-if="hasBlockResult(IS, area, block)">{{block}}</h6>
```